# How to use IDisposable to dispose an object

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, idisposable

I want to use IDisposable interface to clean any resource from the memory, that is not being used.

```
public class dispose:IDisposable
{
        public void Dispose()
        {

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void fun()
        {
            PizzaFactory _pz = new PizzaFactory();   //
        }
    }
```

I want to dispose `pz` object, when there is no ref to it exists. Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's what the garbage collector is for. If all you're worried about is reclaiming memory, let the garbage collector do it for you. `IDisposable` is about reclaiming *unmanaged* resources (network connections, file handles etc). If `PizzaFactory` has any of those, then *it* should implement `IDisposable` - and you should manage its disposal explicitly. (You can add a finalizer to run *at some point* after there are no more live references to it, but it's non-deterministic.)

Answer (score 5):

That sounds more garbage collection, not `IDisposable`.

if `_pz` is disposable and needs to be disposed when the `dispose` instance is disposed (usually via `using`), you could have:

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(_pz != null) _pz.Dispose();
        _pz = null;
    }
```

You *can* do something related with finalizers, but that is not a good idea here.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void Dispose()
{
     _pz.Dispose();
}
```

if PizzaFactory is not IDisposable, you don't need anything. There is the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

vaibhav - wouldn't you be implementing the IDisposable interface in order to use the **using** construct?? that way, it get's disposed of automatically..

jim

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the standard dispose pattern.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx